# Server Error (500) when generating a token on Django Admin page on Heroku what gives?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm in the final stage of wrapping up my API. The last thing I did was create a token via the Django admin page that would authorize my script to upload to the database.

Basic example.py snippet:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token e4fxxxxx000000xxxxx00000xxxxxxxxxx00000'}
r = requests.post(UPDATE_URL_ENDPOINT, json=json_details, headers=headers)
```

Works swimmingly on my local machine. But when I deploy my project to heroku, it doesn't recognize my token so it doesn't accept my post requests. Fine, I say. I'll create a new token on Heroku's servers. So I create a new superuser on their command line, access the admin page, check the Create token page and go click to create a new token. And guess what I see.

`Server Error (500)`

EDIT - console logs as requested:

```
2022-03-10T04:39:03.108381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/add/" host=feh-resplendent.herokuapp.com request_id=bd0031e3-f108-40e5-b1bd-6b233ac6f517 fwd="172.0.0.0" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=66ms status=500 bytes=452 protocol=https

2022-03-10T04:39:03.103921+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.27.67 - - [10/Mar/2022:04:39:03 +0000] "POST /admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://feh-resplendent.herokuapp.com/admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
```

I don't see any glaring issues here.

pulling from heroku logs on the command line (is this what stack trace means?)
`heroku logs -a feh-resplendent`

**EDIT 2:**
Alright, omitted the console logs from the above command. It wasn't helpful and was pretty much doxxing myself. However, on the command line on heroku, I tried creating a token.

`python manage.py drf_create_token username`

to which I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "authtoken_token" does not exist
LINE 1: ...oken"."user_id", "authtoken_token"."created" FROM "authtoken...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/backend/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/backend/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/authtoken/management/commands/drf_create_token.py", line 38, in handle
    token = self.create_user_token(username, reset_token)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/authtoken/management/commands/drf_create_token.py", line 18, in create_user_token
    token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 657, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 492, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "authtoken_token" does not exist
LINE 1: ...oken"."user_id", "authtoken_token"."created" FROM "authtoken...
```

You know what this means? Progress. I'm getting somewhere as I finally have a lead to figure out.

Comment: You'll need to check the heroku logs for information about what is causing the 500 error - there's not enough information here to know what that error could be.

Comment: You need to configure logging of stack traces - what you've posted above is just the request log. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration which does this for you.

Comment: Do you mean in my Procfile?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error. I guess there's an issue somewhere when creating a Postgres database on Heroku (since your local database won't convert and migrate by default), you need to separately initialize authentication token capabilities via the command line on heroku bash:

`python manage.py migrate authtoken`

So now I can finally access the Token option in the Django admin page. Thank you for the tip solarissmoke!